# Inserting all the Gamertags from a game history page.?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out how to get all the gamertags from the output, and then insert them into a mysql table.

This is what I have so far, read the comments... Thank you!

```
<?php
//gameID
$gameid = "469547013";
//key to access api
$apikey = "30cRxVA9J73esG388CzmOXUVRo5VjYhSfI2qBaqcMzs=";

$url = "http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/game/details/".$apikey."/".$gameid."";
$output = file_get_contents($url);

$obj = json_decode($output);

//output
print_r($output);

//json_decoded output 
print_r($obj);

//Having a hard time getting a single gamertag
print $obj->GameDetails->Players->PlayerDetail[0]->gamertag;

//I guess there needs to be an array or arrays here
$result = ????????????;

while ($tag = $result) {
//value
$tag = $array['gamertag'];

//insert each gamertag into table
mysql_connect('localhost', '', '') or die('Error connecting to MySQL');
mysql_select_db('');
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO gamertags(gamertag)VALUES ('".$tag."')");

}

?>
```

Comment: Rather than expose your API Key to everybody, how about pasting some sample data?

Comment: The output excedes the limit for a post and i don't want to link away from site.. the key will be changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
$output = file_get_contents('http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/game/details/30cRxVA9J73esG388CzmOXUVRo5VjYhSfI2qBaqcMzs=/469547013');
$output = json_decode($output);
foreach($output->GameDetails->Players as $player) {
    echo $player->PlayerDetail->gamertag . '<br />';
}
```

**edit** Take a look at http://dbug.ospinto.com/. I through the decoded json into it and it told me exactly how to get what I needed.

Comment: Do I? I use json_decode() on the string from the api so I would assumed it's the decoded json. hahaha I might be wrong on the lingo though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize what dbug does until I read into it a bit more. I thought it was for viewing json objects, not php. Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

Players is an array, so you'll want something like this:

```
print $obj->GameDetails->Players[0]->PlayerDetail->gamertag;
```

So then you'll want to loop through the `Players` array and get each tag. Something like this:

```
$ary = new Array();
foreach($obj->GameDetails->Players as $player) {
    $ary[] = $player->PlayerDetail->gamertag;
}
```